# I can install python package successfully but can not import it. Symbol not found. Expected in:

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, pip, jupyter-notebook, homebrew

I successfully installed pysurvival using homebrew, pip, and gcc, but when I try to import pysurvival into jupyter notebook as so:

```
import pysurvival
from pysurvival.models.simulations import SimulationModel
from pysurvival.models.survival_forest import 
ConditionalSurvivalForestModel
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: 
dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/1.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysurvival/models/_survival_forest.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): 
Symbol not found: __ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE10_M_replaceEmmPKcm
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/1.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysurvival/models/_survival_forest.cpython-37m-darwin.so
Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
in /usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/1.2.4/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysurvival/models/_survival_forest.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

And when I try just:

```
import pysurvival
```

there is no problem.

Is there maybe some conflict between GCC and clang when compiling C++ code?
My OS is Mac OSX Catalina 10.15.1 and I am using Python 3.7.4 but Python 2.7 also exist on my computer.